# Update and delete functions not working in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a bus booking app. But I have a problem with the update and delete function. I am able to update the timings and price. But whenever I try to update the source or destination or bus number...my app gets stuck. When I checked my Firebase realtime database....it looks as if the value is stuck in an infinite loop...as the updated value...keeps getting changed from the old to the new value and new value to the old value continuously. This is causing my app to get stuck. I have two files with regard to this.

1. EditBus.java

```
package com.example.busticketbooking;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Edit_Bus extends AppCompatActivity {
   //Variables
   public EditText busNumEdit,srcEdit,destEdit,timingsEdit,priceEdit;
   private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
   public String BusID;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_bus);
       busNumEdit =findViewById(R.id.BusNumber);
       srcEdit=findViewById(R.id.source);
       destEdit=findViewById(R.id.dest);
       timingsEdit=findViewById(R.id.timings);
       priceEdit=findViewById(R.id.price);
       Button deleteButton = findViewById(R.id.deletebtn);
       Button updateButton = findViewById(R.id.updatebtn);
       FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

       BusRVModel busRVModel = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bus");
       if(busRVModel !=null){
           busNumEdit.setText(busRVModel.getBusNum());
           srcEdit.setText(busRVModel.getSrc());
           destEdit.setText(busRVModel.getDest());
           timingsEdit.setText(busRVModel.getTimings());
           priceEdit.setText(busRVModel.getPrice());
           BusID= busRVModel.getBusID();
       }

       databaseReference= firebaseDatabase.getReference("Bus").child(BusID);
       updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               String busNumVar= busNumEdit.getText().toString();
               String srcVar=srcEdit.getText().toString();
               String destVar=destEdit.getText().toString();
               String timingsVar=timingsEdit.getText().toString();
               String priceVar=priceEdit.getText().toString();

               Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
               map.put("busNum", busNumVar);
               map.put("src",srcVar);
               map.put("dest",destVar);
               map.put("timings",timingsVar);
               map.put("price",priceVar);
               map.put("busID",BusID);

               databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                       databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
                       Toast.makeText(Edit_Bus.this, "Bus updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       startActivity(new Intent(Edit_Bus.this,MainActivity2.class));

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                       Toast.makeText(Edit_Bus.this, "Update Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               });
           }
       });

       deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               deleteBus();
           }
       });
   }
   private void deleteBus(){
       databaseReference.removeValue();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Bus Deleted!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       startActivity(new Intent(Edit_Bus.this,MainActivity2.class));
   }
}
```

2. BusRVModel.java

```
package com.example.busticketbooking;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BusRVModel implements Parcelable{
    private String busNum;
    private String src;
    private String dest;
    private String timings;
    private String price;
    private String BusID;

    public BusRVModel() {
    }

    public BusRVModel(String busNum, String src, String dest, String timings, String price, String busID ) {
        this.busNum = busNum;
        this.src = src;
        this.dest = dest;
        this.timings = timings;
        this.price = price;
        BusID = busID;
    }

    protected BusRVModel(Parcel in) {
        busNum = in.readString();
        src = in.readString();
        dest = in.readString();
        timings = in.readString();
        price = in.readString();
        BusID = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<BusRVModel> CREATOR = new Creator<BusRVModel>() {
        @Override
        public BusRVModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BusRVModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BusRVModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BusRVModel[size];
        }
    };

    public String getBusNum() {
        return busNum;
    }

    public void setBusNum(String busNum) {
        this.busNum = busNum;
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public String getDest() {
        return dest;
    }

    public void setDest(String dest) {
        this.dest = dest;
    }

    public String getTimings() {
        return timings;
    }

    public void setTimings(String timings) {
        this.timings = timings;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getBusID() {
        return BusID;
    }

    public void setBusID(String busID) {
        BusID = busID;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(busNum);
        parcel.writeString(src);
        parcel.writeString(dest);
        parcel.writeString(timings);
        parcel.writeString(price);
        parcel.writeString(BusID);
    }
}
```

3. AddBus.java

```
package com.example.busticketbooking;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Add_Bus extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText busNum,src,dest,timings,price;
    private Button button;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private String BusID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_bus);
        busNum=findViewById(R.id.BusNumber);
        src=findViewById(R.id.source);
        dest=findViewById(R.id.dest);
        timings=findViewById(R.id.timings);
        price=findViewById(R.id.price);
        button=findViewById(R.id.btn);
        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("Bus");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String busNumVar=busNum.getText().toString();
                String srcVar=src.getText().toString();
                String destVar=dest.getText().toString();
                String timingsVar=timings.getText().toString();
                String priceVar=price.getText().toString();
                BusID=busNumVar;
                BusRVModel busRVModel=new BusRVModel(busNumVar,srcVar,destVar,timingsVar,priceVar,BusID);
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        databaseReference.child(BusID).setValue(busRVModel);
                        Toast.makeText(Add_Bus.this, "Bus added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(Add_Bus.this,MainActivity2.class));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Add_Bus.this, "Error is: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, what happen with your delete function ?

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestine If I directly delete without updating anything, then its working properly. but if I try to update something and then try to delete it the its not getting deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
        Toast.makeText(Edit_Bus.this, "Bus updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(Edit_Bus.this,MainActivity2.class));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(Edit_Bus.this, "Update Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

You're adding a listener to the database by calling `addValueEventListener`, which is [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data) as:

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.

Now inside the `onDataChange` you modify the data at `databaseReference`, and as the documentation says that leads to `onDataChange` being called again, which leads to you updating the data again, which leads to...

Since it seems you only want to update the data once, you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to prevent retriggering `onDataChange`:

```
                  // 
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        ...
```

Comment: Hey so I tried this but I its not working. Now the crashing has stopped but the values are not getting updated nor deleted. Instead the add function is also getting called. I'll add the code for add functio now.

Comment: Your original problem was "keeps getting changed from the old to the new value and new value to the old value continuously", which the code and explanation in my answer should help you solve. Nothing else about your app's behavior should've changed because of this change.

Comment: Hey I changed the ```addValueEventListener```  to ```addListenerForSingleValueEvent``` from both EditBus.java and AddBus.java file. Now its Finally working. Thanks a ton!!!